# How to use another method to achieve mysql left join?

Tags: python, mysql

Because MySQL Left join limited 61, maybe this is table:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for test
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (3, 6);
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

This is MySQL SQL:

```
    SELECT
    t1.pid AS lev1,
    t2.pid AS lev2,
    t3.pid AS lev3,
    t4.pid AS lev4

FROM
    test AS t1
    LEFT JOIN test AS t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.pid )
    LEFT JOIN test AS t3 ON ( t3.id = t2.pid )
    LEFT JOIN test AS t4 ON ( t4.id = t3.pid )
    LEFT JOIN test AS t5 ON ( t5.id = t4.pid ) 
WHERE t1.id = 1 ;
```

I want to output like this but not using MYSQL LEFT JOIN:

```
lev1,lev2,lev3,lev4
 3,   6,
 3,   5,
 4,    ,
```

If python can achieve, I also need!

Comment: Is this some heirarachy? If so look at recursive CTE's in MySQL-8.0+ / MariaDB-10.2+

Comment: That limit is in place for a reason, no?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The limit of 61 is there for a reason and your query might run somewhat slowly, but something like the following should work for your needs:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id AS lev1, t2.id AS lev2, t3.id AS lev3, t4.id AS lev4
FROM
    t1, t2, t3, t4
WHERE
    t2.pid = t1.id AND t3.pid = t1.id AND t4.pid = t1.id
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i want , The relationship between id and pid exceeds 61

Comment: What do you mean? I assume you're meaning that you want to select data from more than 61 tables hence why you're hitting the join limit? The query I put should work for more than 61. Or did I maybe misunderstand the question?

Comment: Only one table,I want to find parent node, finally get all paths